# unable to use ssh-1 despite protocol being 2,1 in sshd_config file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

When I do `telnet localhost 22` I get `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1` back. Since my sshd_config file has `Protocol 2,1` in it (vs `Protocol 2`) shouldn't I be getting `SSH-1.99-OpenSSH-6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1` back?

Here's my full sshd_config file:

http://pastebin.com/7kMUtQfn

Comment: What does not support SSHv2 in this day?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file doesn't list any SSHv1-format host keys, so sshd cannot offer that protocol.

Usually the hostkey is at `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_key`; if you have to create it, use `ssh-keygen -t rsa1`.